# How to forward to a web.xml path from inside a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, url-mapping

In my Servlet, I would like to forward to another Servlet by way of calling a path defined in the `web.xml`.

So for instance, in my `web.xml`, I have defined:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I would like to have my servlet map to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/" + user.getUsername()).forward(request, response);
```

However when I go to the Servlet that is supposed to launch this path, the page it returns is blank. Meaning, there is something wrong with the path. I know it is reaching this code because I put Sysout statements before it.

Does anyone know why this isn't mapping properly? I tried every logical combination it seems

**ADDED**

This is the Servlet code that is supposed to handle this path

```
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();            
        Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("^/([^/]+)$");
        Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher(pathInfo);
        if (matcher.matches()){
            String userPath = matcher.group(1);
            my_proj.components.User user = UserManager.getUserByUsername(userPath);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/resources/jsp/user_home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: try remote debugging: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html  Also, try adding some logging.

Comment: @Arvind no, just a blank white page, as if nothing happened (but the Sysout code one line above the dispatch prints in the console)

Comment: @Imray, sop lines won't print on page, use response.getWriter() to print contents on page from servlet(view).

Comment: Well...does your pattern match?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I'm putting in `/user/imray`

Comment: Your pattern says start with a backslash followed and ending with anything but a backslash. However your string has 2 backslashes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis pathInfo only grabs the `user/imray` part of `localhost:8080/my_proj/user/imray`

Comment: Then your pattern still doesn't match.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's not the issue though, because when I manually type in the address `localhost:8080/my_proj/user/imray`, it works

Comment: Debug your application. Add logs statements. Verify the various values of your variables.

Comment: can you show the servlet-class definition for that mapping

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How do I debug `          request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/" + username).forward(request, response);`? How can I check what the actual path it's directing to is?

Comment: In an IDE, you could download and attach your Servlet container's source code. However, the fact that `getRequestDispatcher()` doesn't return `null` or throw an exception means it has found a resource and it is forwarding to it. In this case, I'd simply debug your `Servlet` and check if it actually goes into the `if` block.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It IS going into the `if` block because I am printing out statements in there. It's just dying at the last statement and I can't figure out why

Comment: _dying_ is not very meaningful. By _last statement_, do you mean the additional `forward` call? What's in your JSP?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the help, I ended up finding a way to avoid the problem that is satisfactory to what I need. See my answer.

Comment: Note that this solution is completely different behavior. If you haven't already, review the differences between a `RequestDispatcher#forward(..)` and a redirect.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have, but for some reason one works with the path I'm giving, and one doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Solved, or at least avoided the problem by using a `sendRedirect` instead of a forward.

I.e.

```
        String userPage = "/my_proj/user/" + username;
        response.sendRedirect(userPage);
```